# js to typescript- tried to convert to typescript but got error

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

help to convert js to typescript

```js
const profiles = [{
    name: "kamal",
    age: "20",
    designation: "developer",
    grade: "A",
  },
  {
    name: "arun",
    age: "25",
    designation: "developer",
    grade: "A",
  },
  {
    name: "chan",
    age: "23",
    designation: "developer",
    grade: "A",
  },
];

function profileLookup(name, prop) {
  for (let i = 0; i < profiles.length; i++) {
    if (profiles[i].name === name) {
      if (prop in profiles[i]) {
        console.log(profiles[i][prop]);
      }
    }
  }
}

profileLookup("arun", "age");
```

Comment: What's wrong? Typescript is a superset of javascript, any valid JS is valid TS. You might however run into type errors. If you are, then you need to provide those type errors in the question. It would also help if you included an actual question in the post.

Comment: What is the error? Everything seems to be compiling and executing fine.

Comment: @Olian04 - Oh, would that that were actually true. :-) There are some edge cases around `<` and `>` where TypeScript actually changes the meaning of the code or considers the code to be invalid. Only a few, but they're there...

Comment: Well yes @T.J.Crowder but i doubt that's relevant information for OP.

Comment: @Olian04 It was for you, not the OP.

Comment: @Olian04 What is the error? Why have down voted the answer?

Comment: @ManojKumarNagaraj what error? also i didn't vote on your answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please find the sample code below.

```
    type Profile = {
    name: string;
    age: string;
    designation: 'developer' | 'QA' | 'manager';
    grade: 'A' | 'B' | 'C';
}

const profiles: Profile[] = [{
    name: "kamal",
    age: "20",
    designation: "developer",
    grade: "A",
},
{
    name: "arun",
    age: "25",
    designation: "developer",
    grade: "A",
},
{
    name: "chan",
    age: "23",
    designation: "developer",
    grade: "A",
},
];

function profileLookup(name:string, prop:keyof Profile) {
    for (let i = 0; i < profiles.length; i++) {
        if (profiles[i].name === name) {
            if (prop in profiles[i]) {
                console.log(profiles[i][prop]);
            }
        }
    }
}

profileLookup("arun", "age");
```